# spanner interleaved table lock

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, interleave

let say we have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Singers (
  SingerId   INT64 NOT NULL,
  FirstName  STRING(1024),
  LastName   STRING(1024),
  SingerInfo BYTES(MAX),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId);

CREATE TABLE Albums (
  SingerId     INT64 NOT NULL,
  AlbumId      INT64 NOT NULL,
  AlbumTitle   STRING(MAX),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId, AlbumId),
  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Singers ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I would like to perform a write to the Albums table, is the Singers table locked as well or is just the Albums table locked ?

I have searched for `interleaved table lock` and found a whole lot of nothing.
However I did find [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/transaction-locking-in-cloud-spanner) which has this excerpt :

`Unlike other approaches that lock entire tables or rows, the granularity of transactional locks in Spanner is a cell, or the intersection of a row and a column. This means that two transactions can read and modify different columns of the same row at the same time. To maximize the number of transactions that have access to a particular data cell at a given time, Cloud Spanner uses different lock modes`

Does that mean the parent table is not locked while the interleaved child is updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner does not take table locks, so in that sense the direct answer to your question is 'No'. Instead, Cloud Spanner takes locks at the cell level as described [the article you referenced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/transaction-locking-in-cloud-spanner).

Specifically in the example that you are giving, inserting a row into the `Albums` table requires that the `Singer` record exists. This requires taking a lock on the primary key values of the specific `Singer` record. This again means that you cannot delete the `Singer` record while the transaction that is inserting the `Album` record is still running. You can however update the non-primary key values of the same `Singer` record (assuming that no other statements have taken any locks on any of these cells).

If you do try to delete the `Singer` record while the transaction that is inserting the `Album` record is still active, then one of the transactions will be aborted by Cloud Spanner.